# JSTL Check if a value in an array matches second array

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

its me again.  Basically Im checking the roles of a user once they hit a page.  Its an array, lets say 1,2,3.  The contents of the last column on the jsp for testing has the role #'s that are attached to each individual attachment.  The last column wont be on the finished product, but I need to do some sort of `IF` on that array to see if any of the values in the array:

```
<c:forEach items = "${hotPartRoles}" var = "hpRole"> 
    ${hpRole.id}
    </c:forEach>
```

are in the array of the attachment roles:

```
<c:forEach items = "${item.roles}" var = "role"> 
                    ${role.id}
                    </c:forEach>
```

jsp:

```
<table class="data_table">
<tr>
    <th>Attachments</th>
    //These are the user's Roles
    <c:forEach items = "${hotPartRoles}" var = "hpRole"> 
    ${hpRole.id}
    </c:forEach>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subtable">
    <table class="data_table">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test='${empty attachList}'>
           <tr>
              <td>No Attachments</td>
           </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <tr>
                <th>Remove Attachment</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>File Type</th>
                <th>File Size (bytes)</th>
                <th>File Attached By</th>
                <th>Date/Time File Attached</th>
                <th>Roles</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${attachList}" varStatus="loopCount">
                <tr>

                    <td class="button">
                    <rbac:check operation="<%=Operation.DELETE%>">
                        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:delete_prompt(${item.id});">Delete</button>
                    </rbac:check>
                        </td>
                    <td><a href="show.view_hotpart_attachment?id=${item.id}">${item.fileName}</a></td>
                    <td>${item.fileType}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${item.fileSize}" /></td>
                    <td>${item.auditable.createdBy.lastName}, ${item.auditable.createdBy.firstName}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${item.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <c:forEach items = "${item.roles}" var = "role"> 
                    ${role.id}
                    </c:forEach>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </table>
```

Now the arrays ont need to match exactly, just a value in the array of user roles is in the array of attachment roles....

I need to do the check here to determin whether or not to put a disable flag on the "delete" button:

```
 <rbac:check operation="<%=Operation.DELETE%>">
                        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:delete_prompt(${item.id});">Delete</button>
                    </rbac:check>
                        </td>
                    <td>
```

Comment: Im thinking maybe 2 nested for loops

Comment: `<c:set var="dispVal" value="false"/> <c:forEach items = "${hotPartRoles}" var = "hpRole"> <c:forEach items = "${item.roles}" var = "role"> <c:if test="${hpRole.id == role.id}"> <c:set var="dispVal" value="true"/> </c:forEach> </c:forEach>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing 2 nested for loops and having a var set to false initially, then set to true and checking on that var seemed to work

```
   <c:forEach var="item" items="${attachList}" varStatus="loopCount">
            <c:set var="dispVal" value="false"/>
            <c:forEach items = "${item.roles}" var = "role"> 
                <c:forEach items = "${hotPartRoles}" var = "hpRole"> 
                        <c:if test="${hpRole.id == role.id}">
                      <c:set var="dispVal" value="true"/>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:forEach>

                <tr>

                    <td class="button">
                    <rbac:check operation="<%=Operation.DELETE%>">

                        <button type="button"<c:if test="${dispVal != 'true'}"> disabled="disabled"</c:if>  
                            onclick="javascript:delete_prompt(${item.id});">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom EL function (which shall be an static method in a class, and a proper descriptor in your TLD file). For example a method with signature `boolean contains(Collection collection, Object object)`. And then call it as `<c:if test="x:contains(list, object)">`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.....but the nested for loops I created seemed to work....

Comment: I know it would work, but it is much better to move logic (even this kind of conditions) out of JSP.